# Active Directory Permissions for ArcGIS Enterprise

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, active-directory

I am trying to use our Windows Active Directory to update the Identity Store on ArcGIS Portal (v 10.7.1) and am having trouble getting it to work with a non-admin user.

When we try to update the identity store using the Windows Active directory as described in the [ESRI documentation](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/use-integrated-windows-authentication-with-your-portal.htm) it fails and posts this error to the log:

```
   Could not connect to the identity store as one or more of the connection parameters is incorrect. Verify that you can connect to the identity store outside of ArcGIS Server using the same parameters.javax.naming.AuthenticationException: 
    [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: 
    AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]. 
    AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]
```

We were successful in updating the identity store when using a user with domain admin credentials - but we're not willing to use those credentials in a production situation.

I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem while setting up their instance of ArcGIS Enterprise/Portal.  It appears to be an issue specific to the ESRI requirements for integrating Active Directory to Portal.  I am trying to determine the what permissions are required by ESRI so we can get the user configured properly.

Comment: Have you searched that specific error message? For example I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411665/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecurityc which indicates you entered the right username, but incorrect password.

Comment: We have verified the user name and credentials when we've tested with them in powershell.  On top of that, we're trying to use the credentials that we use everywhere else in our network where we have AD integrations.  The only place they're failing is with the ESRI products.

Comment: We fixed this issue by examining the password we were sending more carefully.  It contained two special characters which needed to be escaped (add a backslash in front of them) in order to be read correctly.